# CSS : Display none to first div of inner div in section

Tags: html, css

I have a **section** and certain divs in that. and there are 3-4 div in inner div.  I want to display none only first div of each outer div.
I want **some text** also to be appeared.

```css
  section div div:nth-child(1){
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<section>
  <div >
    <div >
      first inner div of first outer
    </div>
    <div>
      <div >
        some text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      second inner div of first outer
    </div>
  </div>

  <div >
    <div >
      first inner div of second outer
    </div>
    <div>
      <div >
        some text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      second inner div of second outer
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

> I can't give class to any div.

Any help would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

section > div > div:first-child{
 display:none
}